# How were the heavy elements from iron to uranium made?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stellar-physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Age of the Earth and the star that preceded the Sun](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3833/age-of-the-earth-and-the-star-that-preceded-the-sun)

How were the heavy elements from iron to uranium made?

References: http://www.phy.anl.gov/accelerator_rd/index.html

Review of proposed Tech: http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.nucl.55.090704.151604

Comment: Heavier elements came from dying stars etc. See this question and the first answers for the detailed nuclear processes by which various elements were born: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3833/age-of-the-earth-and-the-star-that-preceded-the-sun

Comment: As this question asks directly about the process that creates heavy elements it is not based on a perticular star and in fact references the possibility of research to prove this theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two main contributions are thought to be from the [s-process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-process) and the [r-process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-process), which are both neutron capture processes that are differentiated by their speed relative beta-decay of neutron rich isotopes.

Both are end-of-stellar-life processes with the S-process probably happening in the giant stages of very heavy stars and the r-process probably happening in core-collapse supernovas.

Comment: +1. Beta decay is exactly what I was thinking about thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unlike light elements, which release energy during fusion, elements heavier than iron require energy for their creation. This happens because the [nuclear binding energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy) is at its maximum at iron. Hence lighter elements were made in ordinary stars, using fusion. However, heavier elements were made in [supernovas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_nucleosynthesis), as huge amounts of extra energy are released during the explosion, some of which is used to force heavy nuclei together and create heavier elements.

Comment: we are all children of stars, came from stardust!!!

Comment: Good start but I asked "How" not "Where" what specific amount of energy does this increase exponentially for each heavier element.

Comment: Not all and perhaps not even most heavy elements are made in supernovae. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/origin-of-elements-heavier-than-iron-fe?lq=1